# mod_rewrite subdirectory to exclude IDs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to use mod_rewrite to make some SEO-friendly URLs with the ID parameter removed

EXISTING URL: http://example.com/companies?id=2&company_name=Company%20One

CHANGE TO: http://example.com/companies/company-one

I am using the id as a $_GET parameter to pull the company info.. but for SEO purposes I'd like to use the readable company name only.

Is it possible to exclude the ID from the URL but still access it to pull the company?

Here is my current .HTACCESS file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

I would like this rewrite to only affect the pages with the companies subdirectory.

Comment: why dont you set the setting of permalink to post name from dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^companies/([^/]+)$ companies.php?companie=$1 [QSA,L]
```